# Hide CustomProperty when printing an Outlook item

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have tried to use the code posted here to hide or disable printing of the customproperty of an Outlook item but when I run I keep getting this error:

{"Method 'Needles.Infrastructure.Outlook.NeedlesCustomProperty.[DispID=107]' not found."}

The property I create is called NeedlesCustomProperty. I create this on all Outlook item object types Mail, Cal and Task. The code I'm using:

```
var item = outlookApplication.GetItemFromID(entryid); //verified returns correct item 

var property = item.GetNeedlesUserPropertyValue(false); //verified returns the custom property I create

long printablePropertyFlag = 0x4; // PDO_PRINT_SAVEAS

string printablePropertyCode = "[DispID=107]";

Type customPropertyType = property.GetType();

object rawFlags = customPropertyType.InvokeMember(printablePropertyCode, 
    BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, property, null);

long flags = long.Parse(rawFlags.ToString());

flags &= ~printablePropertyFlag;

object[] newParameters = new object[] { flags };

customPropertyType.InvokeMember(printablePropertyCode, BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
     null, property, newParameters);
```

Any thought of what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you get the error when you read the old value or when you set it?

Comment: It's when I try to read the old value. This is the line that throws the error    object rawFlags = customPropertyType.InvokeMember(printablePropertyCode, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, property, null)

Comment: What is your version of Outlook?

Comment: Outlook 2016 build 1804

Comment: Are you usre GetNeedlesUserPropertyValue returns UserProperty object, not its value?

Comment: Here is the value returned by property                                          property = {Needles.Infrastructure.Outlook.NeedlesCustomProperty}

Comment: But NeedlesCustomProperty is not the same as Outlook.UserProperty

Comment: Using Redemption I'm able to set the property.    oRdoMailItem.UserProperties.Item("NeedlesCustomProperties").Printable = false; This code works.